# Datawindow sharedata for multiple data window

Tags: xml, powerbuilder, datawindow

Is it possible to share the data of 2 data window into 1 data window? How? And if not, is there any other way to pass the data of 2 datawindow into 1 data window?

Comment: what have you tried? Always post an example of code, and how it fails. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No- you cannot share two datawindow (source) into one. Passing data between datawindows can be done many ways, using GetItemXXX and SetItem function, dot notation, data. An example of what you want to share might help but people will be reluctant to help if you're asking them to do your work.

Comment: I'm not asking to do my work. What I am asking is just an explanation, that's the reason why I didn't post a code because what I need is an explanation Sir Rich Bianco. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: Davide Alberani is one of those stackoverflow trolls that have no idea what the answer is yet feel compelled to point out issues in how you worded the question. You should use the Appeon forum instead. At least he didn't say you were off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.  Sharedata works only from a single source.  If multiple source datawindows have the same column types you can use the Rowscopy method and copy many sources into a single destination datawindow.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Sir Matt. I have a question, in using rowscopy, Does it need that the length of data type of the datawindow(where you are going to store the copied rows) be the same to all data windows(where the rows are from)?

Comment: Yes, numbers to numbers, strings to strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to go back to the 'SELECT' statement ans work with SQL UNION.  For example, fi you have the following SQL statements for your 2 dw:

```
SELECT a,b,c from table1
SELECT d,e,f from table2
```

you could create a new datawindow using the following SQL

```
SELECT a,b,c from table1
UNION 
SELECT d,e,f from table2
```

Of course, the various columns must be of the same type, one by one (a must be equivalent to d, b to e,...).

Alternatively, instead of creating a new dw, you could modify the SQL from dw1, adding (UNION) the SQL of dw2 and retrieving data.

just let me know if you need further details.